# Wrong lock sample

Tags: c#, multithreading

I found thread deadlock sample in book `Programming in C# Exam Ref 70-483` that according my understanding theoretically not always should cause deadlock:

```
public static void Main()
        {

            object lockA = new object();
            object lockB = new object();

            var up = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                lock (lockA)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    lock (lockB)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("LockedAandB  " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    }
                }
            });

            lock (lockB)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000); // Should be added. No in original sample
                lock (lockA)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("LockedBandA " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                }
            }
            up.Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("done");
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
```

To be onest it never gets deadlock in my machine since main thread is too fast to get both lock and release them. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

To make this sample get deadlock we need to add `Thread.Sleep(1000);` also in main thread after `lock(lockB)` line. I'm right?

Comment: A deadlock doesn't need to have a 100% chance of occurring to exist, or to be a problem.  A deadlock that has a low chance of happening is typically *more* of a problem, as you're likely to not notice it in testing and have the code running on live environments.

Comment: But can we assume that added sleep line improves deadlock appear frequency?

Comment: You can run the two code samples a number of times to figure that out easily enough.

Comment: As Patrick's answer demonstrates, there is more than one way to tweak the lock timings to ultimately cause a deadlock (or high probability thereof). You definitely got the fundamental concepts right though - and yes, the added `Sleep` seems like a major "improvement" in terms of triggering the deadlock more reliably.